# How to make image to move on blackberry screen

Tags: multithreading, blackberry

I'm using Blackberry 9800 simulator on Eclipse IDE. my problem is that i really don't know how to make an image to move for my plam game application. Can somebody can help me.. I will really appreciate it.!!thanks in advance gys.!!

Answer (score 1):

Check this BB article: [The BlackBerry Graphical User Interface: Part 2 - Direct Screen Drawing](http://us.blackberry.com/devjournals/resources/journals/jan_2006/direct_screen_drawing.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement paint method for the field in which you want to draw image.
And note that you have to extent the field with full height & width to move the image all over the screen.